# Static files not loading to django project

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

I have a project, where my partner worked on the Frontend without using any frameworks, just used js, html and css. I wanted to attach that front to the back by using Django.

Here are the settings from settting.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join('C:/Users/1224095/work/Backend/backend/static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

I added the {% load static %} in my html header. To not confuse you, I made a static directory named static, and inside I got my assets and plugins from the frontend, plus in every place, I added `href= {% static 'path to the file' %}`.

As a result, I am getting an error of 404, does anyone has an idea why ?
here's an example of my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}

<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{% static 'assets/plugins/simplebar/css/simplebar.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{% static 'assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{% static 'assets/plugins/metismenu/css/metisMenu.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{% static 'assets/plugins/vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{% static 'assets/plugins/highcharts/css/highcharts-white.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: set DEBUG=TRUE in settings.py file

Comment: already done by default

Comment: try to change the first line with STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/1224095/work/Backend/backend/static'

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK5ui61vRtA

Comment: do you get 404 when you load page or in DevTools in  browser when page loads some JS, CSS, Image?

Comment: do you run it on local computer using `django` to run sever, or on internet using Apache/Nginx/etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

(1): You can only use this in your settting.py -> `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

(2): You have to copy and paste your static files (JavaScript, CSS, etc) in your `templates`.

It will look like this:

```
App
|_migrations
|_templates
|_static
    |__App (directory with the App name)
        |_assets
            |_js
            |_css
            |_img
            |_plugins
            |_....
```

Your HTML should look something like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{% static 'App/assets/plugins/simplebar/css/simplebar.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Just don't forget to write App before each 'assets'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).